# How to run function in App.js from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function-call

Sorry, I'm quite new to react.js and Javascript in general so this might be a quite simple answer, but for the love of God. I cannot find an answer that works.
In my `App.js` I have a simple method for reseting some variables.

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import KeyPress from './components/KeyPress';
...
const initialState = {
  text: GetText(),
  userInput: '',
  symbols: 0,
  sec: 0,
  started: false,
  finished: false
}
const ThemeContext = React.createContext(initialState);
class App extends Component {
  
  state = initialState;

  restart = () => {
    this.setState(initialState)
  }
...
```

And in my component file, I have a structure that looks like this.

### KeyPress.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class KeyPress extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default KeyPress
```

**File Structure**

```
src
├── App.js
├── components
    ├── GetText.js
    ├── KeyPress.js
```

How might I be able to call the function `restart()` in `App.js` from `KeyPress.js` (hopefully resetting all the values in `initialState`)

Comment: You would set your state in the parent (or highest-level) component, and pass a reference to the reset method for whatever you're manipulating.  In your parent component (where you're calling the child component) you would pass the reset function as a prop to your child. For example: (in your higher-level return): `<Childcomponent resetValue={restart} />`Then you can call it from inside your child component. Is there a reason you're setting the state in your App component? Is it being shared? A context might be better.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at using context's but at the time that is far beyond my knowledge. Thank you for you information, i'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: I've been getting the answer `restart={restart}`. This does not work as I get `src/App.js Line 61:41:  'restart' is not defined  no-undef` even when I have defined `restart` in `App.js`

Comment: You're not referencing the props in your child component. restart in your child is part of the props object being passed, so you access it by going `const restart = this.props.restart` Think of the props object as like the mail being left in the mailbox from the carrier (the parent). By calling this.props.name, you're opening the mailbox and grabbing the content inside.

Comment: ok, that works. Thank you for the amazing explantion!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your App class component you will have:

```
restart = () => {
    this.setState(initialState)
  }
render() {
        return(
           <div>
            <KeyPress resetMethod={this.restart} />
           </div>
        );
    }
```

Then in KeyPress.js:

```
render() {

return <button onClick={this.props.resetMethod}>Reset</button>;
}
```

Comment: hmm, i'm getting `src/App.js
  Line 61:61:  'restart' is not defined  no-undef` even when I have defined restart as a function in App.js

Comment: I did forget "this" as it should be "this.restart"

Comment: It's so crazy to me that people still use class components. It's been so long since I've used them, I forget all the time about the constructors and the this bindings. Ugh. hahaha

Comment: oh, what do you use now? Am I outdated.

Comment: @JoelHager - People will use class components for quite a bit of time due to existing applications (technical debt) that will require maintenance. And learning it doesn't take so much time.
BuddyBob - all the rage is with functional components.

Comment: I mean specifically newer users defaulting to class components. Everywhere I look it almost seems to omit class-based components. Where are they getting this info from? haha

Comment: Tutorials (like on Udemy/Pluralsight) still cover them, mostly just a short overview which is good as then there will be no surprise when someone will work on some legacy app built with class components.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible solutions:

1. Assuming `KeyPress` is rendered from within `App`, pass the `restart` function as a prop, e.g. `<KeyPress restart={restart} />`.
2. [Use the Context API to manually create a global state](https://codeburst.io/global-state-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-87019cc4f2cf) or use a library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: I've tried your first solution and I get `src/App.js
  Line 61:61:  'restart' is not defined  no-undef`

Answer (score -1):

try exporting the function from app.js an importing it to the comp if it didnt work create a file in the root directory and create and export the function from there

Comment: what do you mean exporting the function?